# Merge the columns and index to create a list - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
              2015    2016

January       10      20
February      20      30
```

I would like this output

```
2015-01   10
2015-02   20
2016-01   20
2016-02   30
```

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: Adding pandas as tag might help

Comment: thanks :) @andreis11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first stack the dataframe, then use `pd.to_datetime` to extract a date value, and finally rebuild a new dataframe:

```
tmp = df.stack().reset_index()
resul = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([pd.to_datetime(tmp.iloc[:, 1] + ' ' + tmp.iloc[:, 0]
                                               ).dt.strftime('%Y-%m'), tmp.iloc[:, 2]], axis=1
                               ).values, columns=['month', 'value'])
```

It gives:

```
     month value
0  2015-01    10
1  2016-01    20
2  2015-02    20
3  2016-02    30
```

Answer (score 0):

First `rename` index values by dictionary, reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) `map` values of `MultiIndex` and last convert `Series` to `DataFrame` by [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html) and [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
d = {'January':'01','February':'02','March':'03',
      'April':'04','May':'05','June':'06',
      'July':'07','August':'08','September':'09',
      'October':'10','November':'11','December':'12'}

df = df.rename(d).unstack()
df.index = df.index.map('-'.join)
df = df.rename_axis('month').reset_index(name='value')
print (df)
     month  value
0  2015-01     10
1  2015-02     20
2  2016-01     20
3  2016-02     30
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
from datetime import date

months={"January": 1, "February": 2, "March": 3, "April": 4, "May": 5, "June": 6, "July": 7, "August": 8, "September": 9, "October": 10, "November": 11, "December": 12}

res=df.stack()

res.index=map(lambda x: date(x[1],months[x[0]], 1), res.index.tolist())
```

Outputs:

```py
2015-01-01    10
2016-01-01    20
2015-02-01    20
2016-02-01    30
dtype: int64
```